# Redirect Calls To A Specific IP To Localhost

Tags: iptables

I've a node server that serves `localhost:90`, and we need to direct all curl calls from WITHIN the machine on `168.92.168.92` to `localhost:90`.

How can this be achieved? Would this be using iptables?

I tried OUTPUT and PREROUTING but the request fails to connect.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3339 packets, 200K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  168.92.168.92 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:90 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3339 packets, 200K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6220 packets, 652K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8         ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL 
2        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       168.92.168.92          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:90
```

Output:

```
# curl -v http://168.92.168.92/hello
* About to connect() to 168.92.168.92 80 (#0)
*   Trying 168.92.168.92... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Curl directly to the server on localhost:90 works, but curl on 168.92.168.92 does not.
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
`iptables-save`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Aug 16 17:21:40 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [51:3060]
:INPUT ACCEPT [51:3060]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [99:10310]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [100:10370]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i 168.92.168.92.168 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:90 
[1:60] -A OUTPUT -d 168.92.168.92.168/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug 16 17:21:40 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Aug 16 17:21:40 2019
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2280:3167420]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
[1165:209934] -A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT 
[12303:3865350] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
[0:0] -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
[24:1440] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
[653:39180] -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1:65535 -j ACCEPT 
[0:0] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 15050 -j ACCEPT 
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
[1:40] -A INPUT -j DROP 
[0:0] -A FORWARD -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 90 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug 16 17:21:40 2019
```

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstand what you're attempting to do: a most trivial thing to do is to simply add the IP-address as a secondary ip-address to your loopback interface with 

   `ip addr add 168.92.168.92 dev lo`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I’ve tried that, and the response I get now is `connection refuse` which is progress?!

Comment: "ip addr add 168.92.168.92 dev lo"  what is the delete command associated ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `filter/INPUT` chain. Better use `iptables-save -c` command to list the full rule set. The packets to `tcp://127.0.0.1:90` should be accepted.

Then check the counters of the `DNAT` rule. It should be incrementing when you run the curl.

The `DNAT` to the localhost (`127.0.0.1`) requires enable of the `route_localnet` sysctl variable. Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and then execute the `sysctl -p` command.

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
```

### Update

From update of the question you can see what the DNAT rule in the `nat/OUTPUT` works because the counter isn't zero. It would  be better make this rule more specific. For example like

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 168.92.168.92 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:90
```

Then check the actual route decision

```
ip route get 127.0.0.1 from <src>
```

Also check the routing rules with the `ip rule list` command.

Next step is add the rules to log the packets from the firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 90 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 10
iptables -I INPUT 2 -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 90 -j ACCEPT
```

And run the `tcpdump -ni nflog:10` command to capture these packets.

Update the question with the new information, what you'll get after these steps.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. Curl to `127.0.0.1:90` works, do I still need to add INPUT rule?

Comment: Paste the output of `iptables-save -c` into the question.

Comment: Thank you Anton; I’ve update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `iptables` nat table `REDIRECT` operation:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --proto tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 90
```

This will redirect any incoming packets (coming in on a network interface from another system) to tcp port 80 to localhost port 90.

That's fine for incoming packets, but for locally generated packets (on the same system) I don't believe it's possible to redirect those to port 90.

Comment: It won't help if the service listens loopback address (127.0.0.1). To redirect the local originated packets the DNAT rule should be placed at the `nat/OUTPUT` chain.